# Why is copy elision so limited?

Tags: c++, copy-elision

The two forms of copy elision I care about are very restricted. It's only allowed in a return statement and when initializing a variable with a temporary. So these don't involve copy elision:

```
// Not initialization
Noisy b;
b = Noisy{};
// Not temporary
Noisy c = a;
```

What is the reason for this? Is it a technical limitation..or..?

Comment: Because the contents of `b`might need to be cleaned-up.  What is `a` ?

Answer (score 4):

The optimisation works by eliminating one object entirely, using the storage for the "target" object that it will eventually be copied to in its place. Then, when the copy is supposed to happen, the target object will already have the right value, so no further action is needed.

This won't work if the target object already exists, since the "new" object can't be created in its place; or if the elided object needs to exist after copying, as it does in your second example.

Answer (score 2):

How do you expect copy elision to work when the thing you're copying from is to remain alive? Your code still has two valid objects, but if you were to elide the copy operation then they would in fact be the same object. Can you imagine how confusing this would be?

```
Foo x;
Foo y = x;
// Now are `x` and `y` the same object, or not?
// Which one will have its destructor invoked?
```

This is precisely why move semantics were invented; you *explicitly* say that you wish to take `x` and move its value into `y`, leaving `x` in a valid but unspecified state:

```
Foo x;
Foo y = std::move(x);
// I've indicated, explicitly, that `x` is not much of anything any more.
// It's my responsibility now to abide by that contract.
```

And if you really do want both `x` and `y` to refer to the same object, then obviously you have references for that:

```
Foo x;
Foo& y = x;
```